# How to get only products with images in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, find, model-associations

```
<?php
class Product extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Product';

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Brand'
    );


    var $hasOne = array(
        'PhotoSmall' => array(
            'className' => 'Photo',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => 'PhotoSmall.tipo = "small"',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
    );

    var $hasMany = array(
        'PhotoBig' => array(
            'className' => 'Photo',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => 'PhotoBig.tipo = "big"',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'PhotoBig.order',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Rating' => array(
            'className' => 'Rating',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

I need all my finds (except in the admin area) to retrieve only products with images.

In the case of `PhotoSmall` is easy, I can do `PhotoSmall.id IS NOT NULL` in a condition because CakePhp generates a left join, but i can not find a way to require a least on `PhotoBig` because CakePhp does two queries to return its results.

The requirement is the following, I can only show products with a `PhotoSmall` and a least one `PhotoBig` system wide (except for the admin section of the site), the solution should work with CakePhp pagination

I've tried the following code without success, it only returns product data, not photo data:

```
$this->Product->recursive = -1;
$conditions = array('Product.category_id'=> $cats);
$joins = array(
    array('table' => 'photos',
        'alias' => 'PhotoBig',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Product.id = PhotoBig.product_id',
        )
    ),
    array('table' => 'photos',
        'alias' => 'PhotoSmall',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Product.id = PhotoBig.product_id',
        )
    )
);
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 12,
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'joins' => $joins,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to additionally use contain - at least that worked for me
(due to your recursive=-1):

```
'contain' => array('PhotoSmall', 'PhotoBig'),
```

the joins are only the setup configuration. without specifying your data you will only get the one model's data.

do you use the containable behavior? would be the easiest solution.
if not, try to set recursive to 0 or 1.

PS: and your second alias is wrong inside the 'conditions' (should be PhotoSmall there).

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you're setting recursive to -1 which should just give you Product data no matter what kind of find you do.

Why don't you do an AND condition in a find on the Product model like so:

```
    $this->Product->find('all', array('recursive' => 1, 'conditions' => array(
    "NOT" => array('PhotoSmall.id' => NULL, 'PhotoBig.id' => NULL))));
```

Note: recursive will need to be at least one because you want related data.