# CakePHP: Using bindModel to trace backwards by 3 models?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have the following models:

`->` = 1:many, `<->` = many:many

**User**`<->`**Product**`->`**MessageList**`<->`**Message**

My goal with this query is to find all **messages** corresponding to the logged in . I also filter out messages that have been read (I find the messages ids in the prior find and store them in `$messageIdsReadByPerson`).

Here is my attempt:

```
        // only grab messages belonging to this user
        $this->Message->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany'=>array('MessageListsMessage')));

        $this->Message->bindModel( array(
            'hasOne' => array(
                'MessageListsMessage' => array(
                    'className' => 'MessageListsMessage',
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'MessageListsMessage.message_id = Message.id'
                    )
                ),
                'MessageList' => array(
                    'className' => 'MessageList',
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'MessageList.id = MessageListsMessage.message_list_id'
                    )
                ),
                'Product' => array(
                    'className' => 'Product',
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Product.id = MessageList.product_id'
                    )
                ),
                'ProductsUser' => array(
                    'className' => 'ProductsUser',
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'ProductsUser.product_id = Product.id'
                    )
                ),
                'User' => array(
                    'className' => 'User',
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'User.id = ProductsUser.user_id',
                        'User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
        $messages = $this->Message->find('all', array(
            'recursive' => -1
        ));
        $this->set('messages', $messages);
```

But that only gives this query:

```
SELECT `Message`.`id`, `Message`.`text`, `Message`.`url` FROM `messages` AS `Message` WHERE 1 = 1
```

How can this be done properly using bindModel (or some easier method that I'm unaware of, although `joins` is apparently not the way to go).

EDIT:
this doesnt work either:

```
function index() {
    // only grab messages belonging to this user
    $messages = $this->Message->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'MessageList' => array(
                'Product' => array(
                    'User.id = ' . $this->Auth->user('id')
                )
            )
        )
    ));
    $this->set('messages', $messages);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the same answer applies as I just gave here:
[How to get only products with images in CakePhp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823602/how-to-get-only-products-with-images-in-cakephp/8826358#8826358)

containable or recursive higher